# SKNavigationDelegate current advice returning nothing

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I am using the navigation in SKMaps and my class is using the SKNavigationDelegate which provides the following method:

```
func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!, didChangeCurrentAdvice currentAdvice: SKRouteAdvice!, isLastAdvice: Bool)
```

The [documentation](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.0/Protocols/SKNavigationDelegate.html#//api/name/routingService:didChangeCurrentAdvice:isLastAdvice:) says that currentAdvice should provide the current advice string. I'm using

```
currentAdvice.adviceInstruction
```

But that is returning an empty string... Am I missing something?

Also in this delegate method I'm trying to use the advice and put it on the screen as a label, however I can't seem to get the label text to appear... I set a breakpoint so I know the method is being called but it just outputs an empty label. Any ideas?

**Edit: added settings:**

In my SKRouteSettings I have

```
let route = SKRouteSettings()
route.startCoordinate = SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().currentCoordinate
route.destinationCoordinate = destinationCoordinate
route.shouldBeRendered = true // If false, the route will not be rendered.
route.routeMode = SKRouteMode.Pedestrian
route.maximumReturnedRoutes = 1
route.requestAdvices = true
```

And SKNavigationSettings

```
let navSettings = SKNavigationSettings()
navSettings.navigationType = SKNavigationType.Simulation
navSettings.distanceFormat = SKDistanceFormat.MilesFeet
SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().mapView.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode.Mode3D
SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().startNavigationWithSettings(navSettings)
```

Comment: Could you add also the code for advice settings. What language are you using?

Comment: I have added some settings. Are they the ones you mean?

Comment: Which language are you using for navigation? English? German? French?

Comment: Indeed - something is not right - we're looking into it

Comment: As a workaround - set the audio config to textToSpeech and intercept either the didUpdateFilteredAudioAdvices: callback (to get only the major instructions) or the didUpdateUnfilteredAudioAdvices:withDistance: callback (to get all the instructions)

Comment: Does this mean I will have to use SKAdvisorResources.bundle in my app too? I'd like to avoid it if I can as that is 57MB

Comment: Yes, you have to include it, but you can remove all the mp3 files (use the TTS option) - this way the size of the bundle is drastically reduced (only some text files remain)

Comment: Update - as of July 6'th - we've made a fix, it will be present in the next SDK release